# c++ mandelbrot function exporting fully black image

Tags: c++, mandelbrot

I'm supposed to be writing a program that exports a Mandelbrot image according to a file, but for some reason the ppm always comes out solid black. I understand that this means the values are always being printed as 0, but I'm not sure why.
The example file I'm using is just 
-1
1
.5
-.5

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <complex>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const int MAXITERS = 225;

struct Complex {
    double real;
    double imag;
};

void input() {
    Complex c1;
    c1.real = 0;
    c1.imag = 0;
    Complex c2;
    c2.real = 0;
    c2.imag = 0;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("mandelinput.txt");
    fin >> c1.real >> c1.imag >> c2.real >> c2.imag;
}


double loc1(double i, Complex c1, Complex c2) {
    double r1 = c1.real - c2.real;
    return i * (r1 / 512) + c1.real;
}

double loc2(double j, Complex c1, Complex c2) {
    double r2 = c1.imag - c2.imag;
    return j * (r2 / 512) + c1.imag;
}
int mandelbrot(double x,double y) {
    Complex z;
    int i = 0;
    z.real = 0.0;
    z.imag = 0.0;

    while (i<MAXITERS && z.real * z.real + z.imag * z.imag < 4) {
        double zt = z.real * z.real - z.imag * z.imag + x;
        z.imag = 2 * z.real * z.imag + y;
        z.real = zt;
        ++i;
    }

    return i;
}

int main() {
    ofstream fout;
    int i,j,m;
    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    Complex c1;
    c1.real = 1;
    c1.imag = 1;
    Complex c2;
    c2.real = 1;
    c2.imag = 1;
    input();
    Complex z;
    z.real = 1;
    z.imag = 1;
    fout.open("mandeloutput.ppm");
    fout << "P3\n";
    fout << "512" << " " << "512" << endl;
    fout << "255\n";
    for (j = 0; j < 512; j++) {

        for (i = 0; i < 512; i++) {         
            x = loc1(i,c1,c2);
            y = loc2(j,c1,c2);
            m = mandelbrot(x,y);
            int r = (m % 255);
            int g = (m % 255);
            int b = (m % 255);
            fout << r << " " << g << " " << b << " ";
            }
        fout << endl;
    }
    fout.close();

}
```

Comment: You could try making a textfile of the iterations themselves, then eyeball it to see if that part is happening correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In `input`, you are creating temporary objects and reading the data into the temporary objects. That does not change the objects in `main`.

You need to pass `c1` and `c2` to `input` from `main`.

```
void input(Complex& c1, Complex& c2) {
    c1.real = 0;
    c1.imag = 0;
    c2.real = 0;
    c2.imag = 0;
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("mandelinput.txt");
    fin >> c1.real >> c1.imag >> c2.real >> c2.imag;
}
```

In `main`, you have two objects that are similarly named and assigned value of `1` to both the real part and the imaginary part. It's not clear to me what the relationships between `c1/c2` in `main` and `c1/c2` in `input` are. However, you'll need to call `input` using two objects of type `Complex`. Whether they are `c1` and `c2`, or some other yet to be created object, I don't know.

Comment: Thank you. I added it to the main to try to fix this and it still comes out blank, any more suggestions?

Comment: Now, you got to use  `input(c1,c2);` in your main method. DId you try that?

Comment: It's still coming out one solid color, but now it's all coming out as all color values being 225.